# How to Carry Flask Variable to JavaScript File

Tags: python, html, jquery, variables, flask

New Programmer Here

So I'm working on a contact form and when I click send I want a message to appear and disappear.
The problem is if some fields were left empty I obviously wouldn't want to show the message because it didn't actually send.
So I was trying to only show the message if the server makes a POST request as opposed to a GET
request because then I know the information was actually stored.

Therefore I used the "post" variable in my html, used jquery to target it and store it in the variable method. But for some reason the if statement isn't being triggered when the the variable "method" does equal "POST"

Tried to explain as best as possible as this is my first time posting.

I know the method value is "POST" when I hit send because it populates on html and I get an alert saying POST

Python Code

```
@app.route("/contact" , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():

    meth = request.method 

    return render_template("contact.html",page=x, post=meth)
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="method">
    {{post}}
</div>

<div class="submit-message">
    <p class="message">THANKS FOR YOUR MESSAGE! </p>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var method = $("#method").html();
    $("#method").hide();
    alert(method)
    if (method == "POST"){
        $(".message").show();
        alert(method);}
    else{
        $(".message").hide();
    }
  });
```

Comment: you dont look like you are importing your js code into your html anywhere

Comment: The problem may be that `{{post}}` is on a line by itself with surrounding whitespace, and the value is actually `"    POST"`.  Put it in the div tag without blank lines: `<div>{{post}}</div>`

Comment: I did just didnt upload the whole file I know its working because I get the alert of what kindve request it is. So the script is working its just not trigeering the if statemen.

Comment: JOHNNNNN THANK YOU SO MUCH